# Renaming subfolders within subfolders

Tags: powershell

I have a folder in the following structure

[image: I have folders in the following structure]

Using PowerShell, I would like to loop through each **subfolder of each person (gender and age folders)** and rename them to gender2 and age2.

To get subfolders of just Persons I tried the following

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:/staff" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -match 'gender' }`

but this returns files in gender folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that you only want directories.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
Path
...
Directory
File
...
#>
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
# Results
<#
...
-Directory
To get a list of directories, use the Directory parameter or the Attributes 
parameter with the Directory property. You can use the Recurse parameter 
with Directory.
...
#>
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Online


(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Recurse -Directory | 
Where-Object Name -match 'Re.*' ).FullName
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\AddressFiles
D:\Temp\NewTree
D:\Temp\ParentFolder
...
#>
```

Or this, without the Where-Object or loop at all...

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Recurse -Directory -Filter 're*').FullName
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\Reference
D:\Temp\Reports
D:\Temp\BonoboGitServer\6_5_0\App_Data\Repositories
D:\Temp\BonoboGitServer\6_5_0\Views\Repository
#>
```

If speed is important to you, then the second one is faster.